# Can I save or fork the current state of Selenium browser?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have several tests to run and all of them share a certain number *x* of initial actions (say login, fill form fields, click buttons, etc.), then they **diverge**.

Is it possible to let the browser execute the first *x* actions just **once**, save the current state and then execute all the test separately (in parallel if possible), each one with a separate browser instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* try to avoid duplicating effort in your tests. However, you **must** aim for consistency above all, and maintainability is probably just as important.

What that means is that using the browser in a way a real user *wouldn't* (I think your state-saving idea counts) is very risky for consistency, and may fail to give you the meaningful results you need.

Another alternative - a 'monolithic' test that attempts to cover multiple scenarios within one user session - is also problematic, because it's slower to run and slower to write and debug.

To be honest I think the idea of "browser state" is one that isn't a good fit for the real web.

My suggestion is to run dedicated, self-contained, clean tests - even if they do duplicate things like login/registration forms. However, if it is important to minimise the length of your test runs, try running them in parallel: ideally on multiple VMs, or via Selenium Grid.